# How to judge quantity of fresh pasta dough per person

Tags: pasta, measurements, menu-planning

Tomorrow I'll be making a big batch of fresh pasta for about 7-8 people.

I know that if I'm using dried or bought fresh pasta, I usually count on about 125-150g per person, depending on the pasta type and whether it is dried or fresh.

When making pasta dough I will add eggs to my flour weight.  Should I just approximate the total weight, and again count on 125-150g per person?  Or will the weight change while I am cooking?

For instance, if I have 1kg durum flour and 16 eggs, the raw ingredients would weigh approximately 1.8kg in total (based on 50g per egg and not allowing for any reduction in weight during cooking).  By my reckoning, that would feed 12 people generously.

Am I correct?

Comment: It depends on what else you are having. An entire egg's worth of fresh pasta is a LOT for one person. I usually fix 1 egg for every two people. Since you are talking metric, I assume you aren't an american, so you might want less than that.

Comment: Dealing with 8 people is small enough that you might have to consider the people -- children and supermodels would eat less than football players and construction workers.  Also, how it's being served -- is it a pasta course before some other course, a side dish to some other main, or is it the main course?  And sauces can affect things, too.  A light tomato sauce, cheese & butter, or garlic & olive oil isn't going to fill you up as much as a heavy meat sauce, carbonara, or a primavera with lots of vegetables.

Answer (score 4):

Michael Ruhlman (in "Ratio") suggests starting with approximately 1 egg per person, and adding the appropriate amount of flour.

Comment: More info on his method: http://ruhlman.com/2011/05/how-to-make-pasta/

Answer (score 2):

I'm a novice but today for the first time made two eggs worth of fresh egg pasta, 200g of 00 flour and 2 large eggs. I ate it all myself, although it was a big portion. I would say that, depending on your sauce and what you are eating the pasta with, 125g is a generous portion per person.

Personally, I was really hungry and had it with just a tomato sauce and nothing on the side, so 200g was alright.